# Recommended way to catch application-wide exceptions?

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

We have developed an extension to capture errors and exceptions in Magento and then forward them to a third-party (in this case Raygun.io).

We are able to use `set_error_handler` to capture errors without trouble, however `set_exception_handler` can not work as Magento captures all exceptions in `app/Mage.php` (this is the case with at least 1.8 and 1.9). Because of this we have resorted to asking users to make a small modification to `app/Mage.php` to forward the exception to our extension.

The code below is added to `app/Mage.php:693`:

```
    die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // BEGIN
    if (class_exists('Springtimesoft_Raygun_Helper_Data')) {
        self::helper('springtimesoft_raygun')->exceptionHandler($e);
    }
    // END

    if (self::isInstalled() || self::$_isDownloader) {
```

Obviously hacking core is bad, is there a better method? Following the logic line by line hasn't shown any alternatives so far, not even a very "hacky" method (for all intents and purposes we can't redefine functions in PHP).

One alternative is to fire a new event here so that at least other extensions are able to make use of this as well. Ideally Magento could add this in a future version (2.x?).

### Edit

As per the answer below, it looks like the best way forward is to periodically check for new exceptions that have been added into `var/log`. This doesn't allow for catching exceptions at the time they occur but is close enough and doesn't require modifying `Mage.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `catch` that is used to handle exceptions in `run()` method inside `Mage.php`

```
catch (Exception $e) {
        if (self::isInstalled() || self::$_isDownloader) {
            self::printException($e);
            exit();
        }
        try {
            self::dispatchEvent('mage_run_exception', array('exception' => $e));
            if (!headers_sent() && self::isInstalled()) {
                header('Location:' . self::getUrl('install'));
            } else {
                self::printException($e);
            }
        } catch (Exception $ne) {
            self::printException($ne, $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

As you can see, Magento uses an event in order to handle all exceptions.

```
self::dispatchEvent('mage_run_exception', array('exception' => $e));
```

The parameter passed to the event `mage_run_exception` is the exception varible itself `$e`. After that Magento is printing this exception with

```
 self::printException($ne, $e->getMessage());
```

So the event `mage_run_exception` is a perfect place for your need. You can observe this event and do whatever things with the exception variable as like this.

`Observer.php`

```
public function ExceptionHandler($observer) 
{
    $exceptions = $observer->getEvent()->getException();

   //do something with $exception here
   if (class_exists('Springtimesoft_Raygun_Helper_Data')) {
       self::helper('springtimesoft_raygun')->exceptionHandler($exception);
   }

    return;
}
```

### EDIT

Unfortunately, it is not possible(As per my knowledge). This is because the `catch` method that you are concentrated in uses php core class for exception. See the definition

```
catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Due to this, you cannot do anything without altering the base code. If magento used any of its own core classes instead of php core class `Exception`, we could have a mere possibility to do this job without touching `Mage.php`. However in this case, it is unavoidable. However you can do below code for better result

```
catch (Namespace_Modulename_Model_Exception $e) {
}
```

where `Namespace_Modulename`  is your own module. This will make `$e` as your own exception class object. Now by decalring the class `Namespace_Modulename_Model_Exception`, you can do anything with exception. In this case your custom exception handing class should looks like this.

File :  `app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Exception.php`

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Exception extends Exception 
{
           //your alreation methods comes here.
}
```

Please note that, I didn't try this before. In theory, it should work.

**Additional Note :-** When developer mode is disabled, Magento places all exceptions in `var/log` directory. By processing files in that directory using file manipulation methods, you can get all exceptions that is generating for each request. For an example you can retrieve exception from those files, place it in an email and then send and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, if you look at the code above you'll notice that before dispatching the event Magento checks `self::isInstalled()` which returns true, leading to `self::printException($e); exit();`. So in most cases we're still unable to catch exceptions with this method.

Comment: oh I see.. then what about other two `catch`es that are appearing above this? How did you handle those errors ?

Comment: We haven't hooked into those exceptions so far as they didn't appear to be useful (the first looks like it handles an expired session and the second handles 404 errors, so we aren't too concerned with these). Though we are certainly open to a solution that can handle all of the above!

Comment: Please go through my edit

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure that renaming the exception would work as all Exceptions would then need to inherit from the renamed class. The `var/log` method is better as it doesn't involve changing `Mage.php`. I previously thought the exceptions weren't being written to `var/log` even with developer mode off, but I will test this further. In this case we still can't catch exceptions at the time they happen but perhaps as early as the next request (or via cron).

Comment: In my openion, use `var/log` method if possible. I think first method will also works, since the custom class inherits from default `Exception` class. However it is not relavant, since it will also demand to alter `Mage.php` directly. When developer mode is off, Magento stores all exception in that directory. If it is on, instead of store those logs, it will throw those errors to user.